# Bash while loop till EOF

Tags: bash

I need to write a program that calculates the arithmetic mean and variance with intiger division, but i don't now how many numbers will be entered. Example input:

```
5

4
1
5

2

6
```

Example output:

```
3
8
```

For now when i enter `x` instead of a number, the loop ends, but those numbers are read from file, so i think it should be something like:

```
while read -r num; do
   if [[ "$num" -eq EOF ]]; then #that condition is my question, what should be inside [[]]?
      break
   fi
   else
      #do sth
done

#the rest of the program
```

Comment: When there is nothing more to read from the input (because you hit ctrl-D or you read from a file), the program will continue after the `done` instruction. No need to add a test inside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get a special value when the end of the input file is reached; rather, `read` exits with a non-zero exit status, which terminates the loop. For example:

```
count=0
total=0
while read -r num; do
    count=$((count + 1))
    total=$((total + num))
done

avg=$((total / count))
```